# Can we implement a C++ style list in Java?

Tags: java, collections, unsafe, memory-layout

An arrayList in Java "holds" references to the Objects and not the actual Object data.

I was wondering if we can implement an arrayList in Java that can contain the Object data directly instead of references. Can Java Unsafe Class be used for this implementation? If yes, what would be the performance of this list in comparison to the existing Java arrayList?

Comment: What benefits would this get you? CPU cache locality at best?

Comment: Yes CPU locality and probably something else that i don't know. This is why I am asking.

Comment: You could always just JNI a C++ list to Java. This might be better than your approach but if your application is mostly Java the benefit would be almost invisible.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/when-using-direct-memory-can-be-faster.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, no.

Java only works with references for objects. What you're describing relies on the low-level control on memory allocation/usage permitting you to allocate a block of memory for 'n' entries. Java simply doesn't work like that - you never have control of the memory and the JVM is at liberty to move the objects within memory. You only *ever* deal with references.

Note also that objects containing references will refer to further distinct memory blocks, and so the concept of an object being contained within one contiguous memory block doesn't really exist here.

If you really want a byte array backed by memory, the [DirectByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) may be of use. It's a `java.nio` class built using the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class. Perhaps you could serialise/deserialise objects to it (calculating carefully the size in order to determine the indexing properly). But the serialisation cost would swamp any other saving, I would suspect.

Comment: You can have low-level control on memory allocation in Java by using java Unsafe class.

Comment: @Brian: You are correct, and I was going to say something similar. But, then I looked up sun.misc.Unsafe: http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

This is what's used to implement low-level things like NIO buffers. _In theory_, it _might_ be possible to make a C++-style list with this, but it would most likely be a slow and extremely convoluted hack. And, as Jesus Ramos said, there's really no use case for it.

Comment: But why do you think this would be slow? Low memory operations in Java are converted immediately into assembly code as JVM handles them as internal operations.

Comment: @karakalos10 Just for a second though think, what would this get you? potentially unsafe memory access around some arbitrary wrapper be it Unsafe class or JNI. Why not use C++ in the first place if you planned on doing this or this was required?

Comment: I am working on my thesis about improving java collections performance. I heard about Java Unsafe class and that it provides low level operations and this is why I am asking specifically about Java. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @karakalos10 In that case, your best bet is probably to code up your own implementation of the list using Unsafe.

Comment: I think it comes down to the fact that the JVM is much better at handling memory than you are. The JVM has been developed for many years to exactly this. There are many white papers on the subject.